# How do I search a pdf for specific words in osx?

Tags: macos, pdf

is there a way to do advanced find?

I can search Theorem in preview but it gives both theorem and Theorem

How do I list all the theorems and lemmas in a pdf copy of CLRS?

for e.g
all theorems start with Theorem x.x 
and lemmas with Lemma x.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Skim](http://skim-app.sourceforge.net/) can do case sensitive search. Click the magnifying glass icon on the left of the search field and select *Ignore Case*. The search in the sidebar can also be limited to *Whole Words Only* (so it doesn't match *Theorems*).

[image]

Comment: I am unable to find the case sensitive switch in skim, where is it?

Comment: @user494461 See edited post. Click the magnifying glass to get the menu.

Answer (score 1):

On Linux I use [pdfgrep](http://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=name&substr=pdfgrep) which has full regex support. It is available for Mac.